# Rails application.js: require all js files in a given directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In `application.js` I have the following line:

```
//= require pivottable/dist/pivot.js
```

However, I want to require all .js files in `pivottable/dist`.  I tried something like:

```
//= require pivottable/dist/*.js
```

or this:

```
//= require pivottable/dist/*
```

But to no avail. How do I require all js files in a given directory in my `application.js`?

Comment: You can use `require_tree` but it may just lead to the code breaking if it has to be loaded in any kind of order.

Comment: how do I add this directory to the tree?

Comment: Use `require_tree` instead of `require`. However as I explained it earlier its just going to give you a new headache down the line. https://github.com/rails/sprockets#require_tree